# Npm FileSaver CSV file encoding for Excel

Tags: javascript, excel, csv, unicode

I'm using FileSaver library on my React application to export data to CSV, the data have characters with accent and when i open it with Excel it doesn't show properly (like this: Ã©) however it shows properly when i open it with another text editor like VS Code
Here's the code i use :

```
            FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([csv], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"}),"id_physique_"+ this.props.secuFoncierExportName+".csv");
            FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([csv_legal], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"}),"id_morale_"+ this.props.secuFoncierExportName+".csv");
```

Does anyone have a solution for this issue ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with this library trying to export CSV files which afterwards are imported to Microsoft Excel.

`file-saver` exports the data in UTF-8 encoding. It seems like Microsoft Excel doesn't use the correct encoding while reading the file via `File -> Open`.

If you import the file in Microsoft Excel via the provided import functionality, you can specify the encoding. You can find the functionality via the menu (`Data -> From Text/CSV`).